# Pandas read data row by row

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a csv file that looks like this

| lon | lat | date1 | date2 | date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1.66 | 2.3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

I want to import it to sqlite database like this:

| lon | lat | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 1 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 2 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 3 |
| 1.66 | 2.3 | 4 |
| 1.66 | 2.3 | 5 |
| 1.66 | 2.3 | 6 |

So I tried following code

```
df=pd.read_csv(root+"/"+i,index_col=False)              
            for j in range(df.shape[0]):
                for k in range(df.shape[1]):
                    lon="'"+str(df[' LON'][j])+"'"
                    lat="'"+str(df[' LAT'][j])+"'"                                          
                    for data_i in df.columns.tolist()[2:]:                                                      
                        value="'"+str(df[data_i][k])+"'"                            
                        insert_data='INSERT INTO day_wl_1 VALUES (%s,%s.%s)' %(lon,lat,value)
```

and it's will make same lot lat but different rows' date

| lon | lat | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 1 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 2 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 3 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 4 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 5 |
| 120.55 | 23.2 | 6 |

how to fix it?

Comment: could you please elaborate the difference of the first and second tables and what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Option one using `stack`:

```
df.set_index(['lon', 'lat'])
  .stack()
  .rename('date')
  .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
  .reset_index()

       lon   lat  date
0   120.55  23.2     1
1   120.55  23.2     2
2   120.55  23.2     3
3   120.66  23.3     4
4   120.66  23.3     5
5   120.66  23.3     6
6   120.77  23.4     7
7   120.77  23.4     8
8   120.77  23.4     9
9   120.88  23.5    10
10  120.88  23.5    11
11  120.88  23.5    12
```

Option two using `melt`:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['lon', 'lat'], value_vars=['date1', 'date2', 'date3'], value_name='date')
  .drop('variable', axis=1)

       lon   lat  date
0   120.55  23.2     1
1   120.66  23.3     4
2   120.77  23.4     7
3   120.88  23.5    10
4   120.55  23.2     2
5   120.66  23.3     5
6   120.77  23.4     8
7   120.88  23.5    11
8   120.55  23.2     3
9   120.66  23.3     6
10  120.77  23.4     9
11  120.88  23.5    12
```